# How to make the close() dynamic?

Tags: angular

```
   <div #child1> <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="closing1()"></div>
    <div #child2>.<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="closing2()">..</div>
    <div #child3>....</div>


    @ViewChild('child1') private child1: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild('child2') private child2: ElementRef;
    ...
    closing1() {
    this.child1.nativeElement.remove();

    }
    closing2() {
    this.child2.nativeElement.remove();
    }
```

How to make the above code optimizied with only1 closing() method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to pass the element ref to the click handler:

```
<div #child1>
   <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="close(child1)">
</div>
<div #child2>
   <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="close(child2)">
</div>
<div #child3>....</div>


close(elem: HTMLElement) {
  elem.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div *ngFor="let child of [1, 2, 3]" #child> <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="close(child)"></div>
```

```js
close(child: HTMLDivElement) {
  child.remove();
}
```

You don't need any reference in your TS.

[See it in action](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yux6kk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

[You can do as many children as you want to](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wgculx?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: I didn't saw your answer at the moment of answering myself. Upvoted  as its mostly the same